# Bootsrapping, use case

Tags: python, statistics, confidence-interval, bootstrapping

I have a very divers data set that I hoped to homogenize with bootstrapping to be able to compare the sample distributions. Here are two parameters each has the 95% confidence intervals for every experimental condition plotted with the original data in black and the bootstrap in red. I am wondering if the discrepancy of boostrapped vs original CIs disqualifies bootstrapping for this data?

Parameter 1:

[image]

Parameter 2:

[image]

Here are the counts for bootstrap (left) and original (right) for the sample data for each group.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on the methodology of getting the intervals? There are many legitimate reasons they can generate different CIs, the easiest one is sample size.

Comment: `df.groupby(['group1','group2','group3']).describe(percentiles=[0.025,0.975])`  I then just plotted those from 2.5% to 97.5% (y axis)

Comment: and for bootstrapping?

Comment: same way. The original df can have between 50 and 2000 events per group (x-axis) while the bootstrapped version sampled 100 events per subject in each group (group sizes vary from 1-11 subjects) and thus the bootstrap has between 100 and 1100 events per group